# Unable to show thumbnail left of Table Cell in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, uiimage, nsdata

I have seen several posts on this here at SO but those solutions don't seem to work for me. Perhaps it's because I'm getting the image URL via JSON. All other text fields in JSON are coming through OK, it's just the image that I can't display and get a SIGABRT error.

The code in question is this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PostCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *post           = [posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString     *postText       = [post objectForKey:@"post_text"];
    NSString     *postAuthorName = [post objectForKey:@"post_author_name"];
    NSString     *postPictureUrl = [post objectForKey:@"post_picture"];
    NSData       *data           = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postPictureUrl]];

    cell.textLabel.text       = postText;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", postAuthorName];
    cell.imageView.image      = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return cell;
}
```

My Table Cell is subtitle with no other changes or wiring.

Any idea where I'm messing up?

PS My full code using `async` request

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PostCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *post           = [posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString     *postText       = [post objectForKey:@"post_text"];
    NSString     *postAuthorName = [post objectForKey:@"post_author_name"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSString *postpictureUrl = [post objectForKey:@"http://example.com/post/1200"];
        NSData   *data           = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postpictureUrl]];

//      NSLog(@"%@", data);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//            [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
        });
    });

    cell.textLabel.text       = postText;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", postAuthorName];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, can you try using `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` instead of `dataWithContentsOfURL`? Perhaps the image type you're expecting can't be properly read or converted to a `UIImage` object. On the side, I think `dataWithContentsOfURL` blocks the UI until it returns. Is that what you want for good scrolling speed?

Comment: john the SDK is throwing an error when I use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:[NSURL URLWithString:pictureUrl]]`

Comment: What does the `postPictureUrl` say? Is it a valid URL with valid image?

Comment: yes it is a valid URL like `http://img.youtube.com/vi/dbf-d8Y--no/0.jpg`

Comment: how many records r there like this?

Comment: @torr is `data` `nil`? Is `cell.imageView.image` `nil` before returning? If either two are the case then you are not loading the image correctly from the network. Also, what you are doing with synchronous networking on the UI thread should never be done if you want an app that is usable.

Comment: @CarlVeazey you are correct - `data` returns nothing in log even when I hardcode the URL - please see new code on OP that includes an `async` method which I left out for brevity - how do you troubleshoot the bad loading of image?

Comment: @Prince there could be 50+ records as this is a JSON stream of blog posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minor changes and the below works (ie, thumbnail shows to the left of title and subtitle).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *post           = [posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text       = [post objectForKey:@"post_text"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [post objectForKey:@"post_author_name"];

    NSString *postpictureUrl = [post objectForKey:@"picture"];
    NSData   *data           = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postpictureUrl]];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return cell;
}
```

Note the use of `initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` instead of `Default`.

The guide here is an important read:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Finally, note this is synchronous downloading of images which will not work in the real world.
So I'll be posting another question on SO about the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like in :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(downloadImages:) toTarget:self withObject:  [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imageURL,@"imageURL",[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:indexPath.row],@"indexPath", nil]];
```

call above function and

```
- (void) downloadImages:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict{

    NSURL *nurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"imageURL"]];

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nurl];
    NSURLResponse * response;

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: req returningResponse: &response error: &error];


    UITableViewCell *cell = [YOURTABLENAME cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)[dict objectForKey:@"indexPath"]];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    if (error) {...handle the error}
}
```